# Typo3 Search Crawler Configuration

Tags: search, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I use Typo 7.6.10

I followed instruction to index news but it doesn't work.
I created a Crawler Configuration in the "Single News Page" with this configuration

```
&tx_news_pi1[news]=[_TABLE:tx_news_domain_model_news;_PID:1]
```

But when i search in result page i found only one news and the link is wrong, link point to the single page of the news.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue.

I checked "Append cHash" in crawler configuration and now in the result of search I have the correct link urls.